# How can i get pixels from a specific area of the screen in C# very fast?

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, directx

I want to calculate average pixels color from a specific area of the screen. I'm making a LED backlight for my TV so it needs to be very fast. At least 30fps. Bitmap.GetPixel() is too slow for it. I found an OpenGL method Gl.ReadPixels()  but i don't know how it works. It recieving int[] as a data to return. But after calling this method i only get an array full of 0. How can i use this method? Or maybe there is some other way for this task?

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object

Comment: `glReadPixels` works only for images that have been drawn with OpenGL render context `glReadPixels` is called with. You can't use (reliably) use `glReadPixels` to read arbitrary screen contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the fastest way to process images in C# is through `pinvoke` using Win32 Gdi32 and User32 functionality.

Here is some C# code which captures the current desktop. Optionally you can pass the filepath of a 'mask' image which can be used to isolate a region(s) of the desktop capture. In the mask, texel which is black (with alpha 0) will be discarded from the screen grab. It's quite rudimental since it only supports 32-bit images and requires the mask and screen capture to be the same size. You welcome to improve on it in your own way, or you can see how image processing is done on a texel by texel basis by hooking directly into the Win32 functions with `pinvoke` (see constructor).

```
public class ScreenCapture
{
    private System.Drawing.Bitmap capture;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="maskFile">Optional mask file, use "" for no mask</param>
    public ScreenCapture( string maskFile )
    {
         // capture the screen
         capture = CaptureWindow(User32.GetDesktopWindow());

         // if there is a mask file, load it and apply it to the capture
         if (maskFile != "")
         {
             string maskfilename = maskFile + ".png";
             System.Drawing.Bitmap maskImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(maskfilename) as Bitmap;

             // ensure mask is same dim as capture...
             if ((capture.Width != maskImage.Width) || (capture.Height != maskImage.Height))
                throw new System.Exception("Mask image is required to be " + capture.Width + " x " + capture.Height + " RGBA for this screen capture");

             Rectangle rectCapture = new Rectangle(0, 0, capture.Width, capture.Height);
             Rectangle rectMask = new Rectangle(0, 0, maskImage.Width, maskImage.Height);

             System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData dataCapture = capture.LockBits(rectCapture, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
             System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData dataMask = maskImage.LockBits(rectCapture, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

             IntPtr ptrCapture = dataCapture.Scan0;
             IntPtr ptrMask = dataMask.Scan0;

             int size = Math.Abs(dataCapture.Stride) * capture.Height;

             byte[] bitsCapture = new byte[size];
             byte[] bitsMask = new byte[size];

             System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptrCapture, bitsCapture, 0, size);
             System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptrMask, bitsMask, 0, size);

             // check each pixel of the image... if the mask is 0 for each channel, set the capture pixel to 0.
             for (int n = 0; n < size; n += 4)
             {
                 bool clearPixel = true;
                 for ( int c = 0; c < 4; ++c )
                 {
                     // if any pixel of the mask is not black, do not clear the capture pixel
                     if (bitsMask[n + c] != 0)
                     {
                         clearPixel = false;
                         break;
                     }      
                }
                if ( clearPixel )
                {
                    bitsCapture[n] = 0;
                    bitsCapture[n + 1] = 0;
                    bitsCapture[n + 2] = 0;
                    bitsCapture[n + 3] = 0;
                }
            }

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bitsCapture, 0, ptrCapture, size);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bitsMask, 0, ptrMask, size);
            capture_.UnlockBits(dataCapture);
            maskImage.UnlockBits(dataMask);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The handle to the window. 
        /// (In windows forms, this is obtained by the Handle property)</param>
        /// <returns>Screen grab image</returns>
        private System.Drawing.Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            // get te hDC of the target window
            IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);

            // get the size
            User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
            User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
            int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
            int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;

            // create a device context we can copy to
            IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);

            // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
            // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
            IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);

            // select the bitmap object
            IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);

            // bitblt over
            GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);

            // restore selection
            GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);

            // clean up
            GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
            User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

            // get a .NET image object for it
            System.Drawing.Bitmap img = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);

            // free up the Bitmap object
            GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            return img;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save this capture as a Png image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">File path and name not including extension</param>
        public void SaveCapture( string filename )
        {
            capture.Save(filename + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing Gdi32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class GDI32
        {
            public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
                int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
                int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
                int nHeight);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing User32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class User32
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct RECT
            {
                public int left;
                public int top;
                public int right;
                public int bottom;
            }
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);
        }
    }
```

It throws exceptions, so be sure to catch them. To use...

```
ScreenCapture grab = new ScreenCapture( "screenGrabMask.png" );
grab.SaveCapture( "screenGrab.png" );
```

Comment: Graphics.CopyFromScreen is likely faster (no extra copies) and much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Bitmap.LockBits
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx

to provide some basic idea

```
    private unsafe void demo(Bitmap bm)
    {
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData D = bm.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        int stride = Math.Abs(D.Stride);
        byte* pImg = (byte*)D.Scan0.ToPointer();
        for(int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++)
        {
            byte* pRow = (byte*)(pImg + y * stride);
            for(int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x++)
            {
                uint b = *pRow++;
                uint g = *pRow++;
                uint r = *pRow++;
                pRow++; // skip alpha
                // do something with r g b
            }
        }
        bm.UnlockBits(D);
    }
```

Allow unsafe code (be careful) to avoid extra memory copies.